# boostrap select search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got `bootstrap-select` error when trying to use `data-live-search`

Using the latest version from github referenced as such

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-select.css">

<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

and the form

```
    <select class="selectpicker float-bottom country-residence" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="">{{ profile.country|default:"----Select One----" }}</option>
      {% for co in countries %}
        <option value="{{ co.0 }}">{{ co.1 }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
    at $.expr.pseudos.icontains (bootstrap-select.js:199)
    at jquery.js:15
    at jquery.js:15
    at jquery.js:15
    at bm (jquery.js:15)
    at bm (jquery.js:15)
    at Z (jquery.js:15)
    at Function.Z.matches (jquery.js:15)
    at Function.filter (jquery.js:15)
    at bj (jquery.js:15)
```

`bootstrap-select` 195-200

```
// Case insensitive contains search
$.expr.pseudos.icontains = function (obj, index, meta) {
  var $obj = $(obj);
  var haystack = ($obj.data('tokens') || $obj.text()).toString().toUpperCase();
  return haystack.includes(meta[3].toUpperCase());
};
```

[record-preview](https://youtu.be/K_VW8s_dDVQ) of error

Comment: my best guess is that it might has something to do with `haystack.includes(meta[3].toUpperCase());`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen why though is the question